# Wordpress Astra theme how do I use wp_redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to use `wp_redirect` inside this function but I am currently getting an error:

> Cannot Modify Header Information. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Here is my code:

```
function add_listing_dashboard_content() {

    global $post;

    global $page_id_dashboard; 
    global $page_id_user_profile;
    global $page_id_submit_listing;  
    global $page_id_success;     
    
    $page_id_dashboard      = get_field( 'dashboard_page', 'option');
    $page_id_user_profile   = get_field( 'user_profile_page', 'option');
    $page_id_submit_listing = get_field( 'submit_listing_page', 'option');
    $page_id_success        = get_field( 'success_page', 'option');
    
    if ( is_page( $page_id_dashboard ) && is_user_logged_in() ) :   
        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-dashboard.php');        
    elseif ( is_page( $page_id_success ) && is_user_logged_in() ) : 
        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-dashboard.php');                
    elseif ( is_page( $page_id_user_profile ) && is_user_logged_in() ) :    
        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-profile.php');      
    elseif ( is_page( $page_id_submit_listing ) && is_user_logged_in() ) :  
        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-submission.php');           
    elseif ( is_page( $page_id_dashboard ) || is_page( $page_id_user_profile ) || is_page( $page_id_submit_listing ) && !is_user_logged_in() ) :        
        include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-loggedout.php');
    elseif ( is_page( $page_id_success ) && !is_user_logged_in() ) :
        wp_redirect( get_permalink($page_id_dashboard) );       
        exit;
    endif;  
    
}
add_action( 'astra_entry_content_after', 'add_listing_dashboard_content' );
```

Comment: I think `astra_entry_content_after` hook is too late for a redirect. Try to use `template_redirect` hook instead.

Comment: Kind of works. Unfortunately though, using template_redirect forces my content to appear before the header and messes up my layout completely.

Comment: Well you could use **both of them**. First use `template_redirect` to check whether you're on the right page or not, if not, redirect. Second, if you're on the right page, use `astra_entry_content_after` hook to insert your templates.

Comment: How do I place a function within another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, `astra_entry_content_after` is too late for performing a redirect. So, you could use both `template_redirect` hook and `astra_entry_content_after` hook separately not "inside each other". Use the following snippets in the `functions.php` file:

```php
add_action("template_redirect", "redirecting_users_on_page_id_success");

function redirecting_users_on_page_id_success()
{
    global $page_id_dashboard;
    global $page_id_success;

    $page_id_dashboard = get_field('dashboard_page', 'option');
    $page_id_success   = get_field('success_page', 'option');

    if ((is_page($page_id_success) && !is_user_logged_in())) 
    {
        wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink($page_id_dashboard));
        exit;
    }
};
```

```php
add_action('astra_entry_content_after', 'add_listing_dashboard_content');

function add_listing_dashboard_content()
{

    global $page_id_dashboard;
    global $page_id_user_profile;
    global $page_id_submit_listing;
    global $page_id_success;

    $page_id_dashboard      = get_field('dashboard_page', 'option');
    $page_id_user_profile   = get_field('user_profile_page', 'option');
    $page_id_submit_listing = get_field('submit_listing_page', 'option');
    $page_id_success        = get_field('success_page', 'option');

    if (is_page($page_id_dashboard) && is_user_logged_in()) :
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-dashboard.php');
    elseif (is_page($page_id_success) && is_user_logged_in()) :
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-dashboard.php');
    elseif (is_page($page_id_user_profile) && is_user_logged_in()) :
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-profile.php');
    elseif (is_page($page_id_submit_listing) && is_user_logged_in()) :
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-submission.php');
    elseif (is_page($page_id_dashboard) || is_page($page_id_user_profile) || is_page($page_id_submit_listing) && !is_user_logged_in()) :
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../templates/partials/dashboard-loggedout.php');
    endif;
}
```

Let me know if you could get it to work!

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you for your help. Most appreciated.